# How to force Firefox suggest a specific link when typing a character?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, hyperlink, address-bar

For example, when I want to go to `www.getpocket.com`, my mind only remember the product name (*Pocket*), not the actually URL. When I typing `poc`, the first suggestion is the link that I want to go, but I have to manually select it by going down:
[image: image description]

Another example, when I want to go to *my Pinterest profile*, I start typing in `pin`, but Firefox only pre-select `pinterest.com`, not `pinterset.com/Ooker777`, although it's the only page I visit (I actually have deleted all `pinterset.com` suggestions)

[image: image description]

In both examples, I want Firefox to autoselect the first selection, so all I need is to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addon [**Redirector**](http://einaregilsson.com/redirector/) is born for this. It is available not only for Firefox, but also for Chrome and Opera.

Also, I realize that I can also do this without any addon installed. Pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> is fast enough.